# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS sleep state every 30 seconds

Tags: suspend

So I installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS onto my laptop a few days ago and have run into a strange problem. If I shut the lid on my laptop and allow the computer to go into sleep mode, when I try to use it next it will go back into sleep mode about every 30 seconds. The only way I have found to fix it so far is to do a hard restart.

I also tried changing settings in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to:

```
 HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Any suggestions on what to do?

**dmesg log before shutting lid:**

```
[    1.063558] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:19/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    1.063567] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
```

**dmesg log after shutting lid:**

```
[    1.063558] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:19/PNP0C09:01/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    1.063567] ACPI: Lid Switch [LID0]
[ 3862.929353] ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
```

**Hardware:**
 - 2017 Razer Blade
 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

**edit 1:**
Leaving the lid open and letting the laptop sleep does not lead to this problem

**edit 2:**
I've found that setting

```
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
```

fixes the issue

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please add logs from dmesg starting from the time you close the lid of the laptop. You can edit and update your question to include the additiona info. Also include some details about the machine hardware and setup. That will greatly help in trying to figuring out what is goind on.

Comment: Thank you! For me I only had to do "HandleLidSwitch=ignore", but this fixed the issue I was having with my Razer Blade 14". Running "sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind" fixed it on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

My colleges and I were having the same issue on the Lambda Labs Tensorbook made by Razor running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

This issue has been addressed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RazerBlade

The OS does not detect that the lid has been opened if the laptop is suspended. This can be fixed through the following modification:

Edit the default grub config:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Add `button.lid_init_state=open` to the end of the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option, like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash button.lid_init_state=open"
```

Run the following command to update grub once you are done:

```
sudo update-grub 
sudo reboot
```